# Inject css after loading a JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, css, sharepoint, csom

I have a JavaScript function that retrieve Yammer feed in a SharePoint site :

```
<div id="embedded-feed" style="height:317px;width:359px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s0.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
yam.connect.embedFeed({
  container: "#embedded-feed",
  network: "mynetwork",
  feedType: "group",
  feedId: "all"
});

</script>
```

When it's loaded it look like this :

```js
<div id="embed" class="yj-embed yj-embed-narrow"><div class="yj-hd">
  <h3 style="background-color: #75150D; color:#FFFFFF; margin: 0px;" role="heading" aria-level="1">The Duck</h3>
  <h2 class="yj-acc-hidden"><span>Message Composer</span></h2>
<div class="yj-global-embed-publisher-with-avatar"><div class="publisher-avatar"><div data-userid="1587566802" class="yj-avatar" aria-hidden="true">  <a class="yj-avatar--link " href="https://www.yammer.com/mynetwork.fr/#/users/1587566802" tabindex="-1" title="">
      <span class="yj-avatar--thumb yj-avatar--replacement yj-avatar--replacement-color-9 yj-avatar--replacement-letters-2">
          <span class="yj-avatar--initials" aria-hidden="true">VP</span>
          <span class="yj-avatar--alt-text yj-acc-hidden"></span>
      </span>
  </a>
</div></div>
```

[image]

I wanna change the background color of the `<h3>` tag using JavaScript, I tried this code :

`$('#embed h3').css('    background-color', 'black');`

but it doesn't work, I think the Yammer feed is loaded after my second function which change the code, that's why it doesn't do anything.

do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Where is the file located in which you try to set the `background-color` property with `$('#embed h3').css('    background-color', 'black');`?

Comment: it's located (loaded using a JavaScript function i've show you in my post ), in a web part in my SharePoint page

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking about setting the background-color in JavaScript - it is possible.
But since you are using a scripteditor-web part anyway to embed the yammer-feed, why don't you use CSS?
The "!important" is to override the inline styling.

```
<style>
#embed h3 {
   background-color: black !important;
}
</style>
```

You could also try to use _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames. This calls the function a bit after $(document).ready...

```
function setCss () {
   $('#embed h3').css('background-color', 'black !important');
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('setCss');
```